# Python threading does not start

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote a large program that processes a big data set of 70k documents. Each docu takes about 5 seconds, hence I want to parallelize the procedure. The code doesn't work and I can't make sense of why. I tried it with one worker only, to make sure it's not a memory issue.

**Code:**

```
from doc_builder import DocBuilder
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import threading

path = "/home/marcel/Desktop/transformers-master/examples/token-classification/CORD-19-research-challenge/document_parses/test_collection"
paths = [x for x in glob(path + '/**/*.json', recursive=True)]
workers_amount = 1

def main(paths):
    doc_builder = DocBuilder()
    for path in tqdm(paths):
        data, doc = doc_builder.get_doc(path)
        doc_builder.write_doc(path, data, doc)

threads = []
for i in range(workers_amount):
    worker_paths = paths[int((i-1/workers_amount)*len(paths)):int((i/workers_amount)*len(paths))]
    t = threading.Thread(target=main, args=[worker_paths])
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

It just randomly finishes executing after a while. CPU threads do spike when starting but besides that nothing really happens. Is there something wrong with the code? If thats important I am running this on a Ryzen 7 3700X (so 16 threads should be possible).

/edit: At first I thought the problem might be that each thread initalizes a large PyTorch model and a trainer like this:

```
self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(self.pretrained_dir) #, cache_dir=cache_dir)
self.splitter = spacy.load(cd_dir + "/en_core_sci_md-0.2.4/en_core_sci_md/en_core_sci_md-0.2.4")
self.model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(self.pretrained_dir, config=self.config_dir) #,cache_dir=cache_dir)
self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(self.model_dir))
self.trainer = Trainer(model=self.model, args=TrainingArguments(output_dir=self.output_dir))
```

This could be shared amongst the threads, so I don't need to initialize a new one every time (initializing those is very costly), but as I said, I tried using 1 worker, so really, that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: What happens that is not the desired behaviour? Is an error thrown?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything.. I put a print statement behind `doc_builder = DocBuilder()` but it doesn't even get there!

Comment: Nevermind, it just got there and printed it out 3 times.. I guess I have to go deeper..

Comment: So, it never enters the for loop.. it executes before that.

Comment: You are probably running into issues with the GIL. Threads in Python can only run one at a time. It bounces back and forth between threads for the illusion of concurrency. Try using multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Just tried that, same behaviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you maybe try it using the ThreadPoolExecutor? Takes away the headache of managing the pool.
Syntax may not be 100% right. I never used tqdm.

```
from doc_builder import DocBuilder
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

path = "/home/marcel/Desktop/transformers-master/examples/token-classification/CORD-19-research-challenge/document_parses/test_collection"
files = [x for x in glob(path + '/**/*.json', recursive=True)]

WORKERS_AMOUNT = 16

def main(file):
    doc_builder = DocBuilder()
    data, doc = doc_builder.get_doc(tqdm(file))
    doc_builder.write_doc(file, data, doc)

threads = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=WORKERS_AMOUNT) as executor:
    for file in files:
        threads.append(executor.submit(main, file))
```

Comment: Will try that next, I may have found a bug in my program.

Comment: do you know why my CPU is not fully being used though? I am using 16 workers, because I thought thats how many threads my CPU can run. However, it's only at ~25% workload.

Comment: Thats because of the the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). It basically works as designed.
If you want to utilise all cores, look into multiprocessing. I am not experienced with it´s usage though and don´t know if you can combine the multiprocessing with the ThreadPoolExecutor.